# Any reason my jquery function isn't setting the top attribute for the element I asked it to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

Any reason this code is not changing the CSS `top` property of my `#image div`?

```
$(function() {
    console.log($("#image").css('top'));
    $("#image").css("top",($("#maincontent").outerHeight(true)/2)-255 + "px");
    console.log($("#image").css('top'));
});
```

I am not very skilled with jQuery, so I understand if some of it is wrong, or all of it, but both helping assist with the problem and telling me what I did wrong would be very useful.

Here is the JSFIDDLE:
https://jsfiddle.net/tg3vvh3v/1/

My entire HTML document looks like:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="head" -->
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
<link href="../Module 10/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
};

$(function() {
    console.log($("#image").css('top'));
    $("#image").css("top",($("#maincontent").outerHeight(true)/2)-255 + "px");
    console.log($("#image").css('top'));
}); 

</script>

<body onload="MM_preloadImages('../Module 10/Home-Page-Roll.png','../Module 10/Intro-Roll.png','../Module 10/Lesson-Roll.png','../Module 10/Final-Roll.png','../Module 10/website_design_dpk.png','../Module 10/website_design_dpk-roll.png','../Module 10/tools-html-coding.jpg','../Module 10/Website Desiging.png','../Module 10/Final Exam.jpg')">

<div id="header">
<a href="../Module 10/Index.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Header','','../Module 10/website_design_dpk-roll.png',1)"><img src="../Module 10/website_design_dpk.png" alt="Header that leads back to index page" width="850" height="320" id="Header" /></a> </div>

<div id="nav">
<a href="../Module 10/Index.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Home','','../Module 10/Home-Page-Roll.png',1)"><img src="../Module 10/Home-Page-Org.png" alt="Link to home page" width="161" height="80" id="Home" /></a>
<a href="../Module 10/Intro.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Intro','','../Module 10/Intro-Roll.png',1)"><img src="../Module 10/Intro-Orig.png" alt="Link to introduction of lesson" width="161" height="80" id="Intro" /></a> 
<a href="../Module 10/Lesson.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Lesson','','../Module 10/Lesson-Roll.png',1)"><img src="../Module 10/Lesson-Orig.png" alt="Link to lesson page" width="161" height="80" id="Lesson" /></a> 
<a href="../Module 10/Final.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Final','','../Module 10/Final-Roll.png',1)"><img src="../Module 10/Final-Orig.png" alt="Link to Final of lesson" width="161" height="80" id="Final" /></a></div>

<div id="wrapper">
<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="Main Content" -->

<div id="maincontent">
 <h2>Lesson  2.04: What makes a good web site?</h2>
  <p><BR>
  </p>
  <p>All  new web designers can learn a great deal about what looks good and  what looks not so good by studying the design of pages they see on  the Web. A new web designer has many factors to think about while  producing their pages including the content, the overall look of the  pages, the color scheme, the aesthetics, and the ease of navigation.  Please keep the following elements in mind when designing your own  web pages later in this module.</p>
  <p><BR>
  </p>
  <h3> Design  Tips</h3>
  <p><BR>
  </p>
  <p>Here  are a few tips that will help any web designer create great web pages  and ultimately great web sites! </p>
  <p><BR>
  </p>
  <p>Keep  your content concise and free of grammatical, spelling, and  typographical errors. Your content should be short and to the point.  It should also be looked upon as a credible source of information. </p>
  <p><BR>
  </p>
  <p>Keep  your web pages consistent. By using the same color scheme, heading  format, text, buttons, and style, you make it easy for the viewer to  understand they are still on your web site and have not been taken to  another location on the Web by clicking on a link. </p>
  <p><BR>
  </p>
  <p>Always  use contrasting colors for your background and text. This makes it  easy for the viewer to read. Steer clear of using busy backgrounds  that are hard to read. Please remember it is very difficult to read  text that is put on a textured or patterned background. </p>
  <p><BR>
  </p>
  <p> It is  considered &quot;good design&quot; to maintain pages that are simple  and do not use all the bells and whistles that are available. Using  animations, gimmicks, flashy backgrounds, etc. should all be done in  moderation. </p>
  <p><BR>
  </p>
  <p>Do not  use large images. Large images take a long time to download. Please  keep this in mind and use small images that add meaning to the  content of your page. Do not use images simply for decoration.</p>
  <p><BR>
  </p>
  <p> The  rule of thumb is that the image should be no larger than 300 pixels  on either side or 25k in size. If the image is larger and it is  important to show the entire image, then you should use a thumbnail  image on your web page and link the thumbnail image to the larger  image.</p>
  <p><BR>
  </p>
  <p>Preview  your pages in multiple browsers to make sure you are happy with the  way they look. Often pages will look different in Firefox, Internet  Explorer, Safari, and others. </p>
  <p><BR>
  </p>
  <p>Always  check to make sure your links are properly working and to check your  links to the outside frequently. A good web designer knows that  revisions and updates are mandatory to maintain a good web site.</p>
  <p><BR>
  </p>
  <h3>Web  Design Resources</h3>
  <p><BR>
  </p>
  <p>Please  visit the following links to learn more about web design.</p>
 <i> <p>•   https://www.gov.uk/designprinciples</p>
  <p>•  http://www.famouslogos.org/good-website-design-tips</p>
  <p>•  http://andrewpritchard.com/2007/website-design-what-not-to-do/</p>
  <p>•  http://problemwebsites.com/</p>
  </i>
</div>

<!-- TemplateEndEditable --><!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="Background image" -->

<div id="image" style="background-image: ;">

</div>
<!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <h3>Thank you for visitng WWVS! Please remember to check your pace schedule and remember if work is not submitted every 2 weeks, you will be removed from your course! </h3>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS can be found on my [jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/tg3vvh3v/1/)

Comment: Probably because you're missing a dollarsign before `("#image")`

Comment: didn't change anything

Comment: Without seeing the rest of the CSS applying to the `#image`, it is impossible to tell why. The image size and position could be over-constrained, leading to application of the extremely complex rules for resolving over-constrained position/size.  The only realistic way to debug this is to examine the applied _and computed_ attributes it in a browser's debugger toolset. One basic question is the `#image` div fixed/absolutely positioned?

Comment: Your fiddle has some errors.  I put a console log in your document ready that is not printing.  Make sure to fix your errors first as that can cause the entire script to stop.

Comment: what errors? I thought it was fine

Comment: There isn't enough code in the question to tell what the problem is. Questions should not depend on third party hosted code to be understandable … not to mention that the code you have externally hosted is huge. You need to create a proper test case, here on Stackoverflow. http://sscce.org/

Comment: That works perfectly, but how did that work? I know console log prints out the results but I don't see how that would influence the code working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/tg3vvh3v/2

```
$(function() {
    console.log($("#image").css('top'));
    $("#image").css("top",($("#maincontent").outerHeight(true)/2)-255 + "px");
    console.log($("#image").css('top'));
});
```

I added jquery to the fiddle javascript cog and made it include the script in the head so your functions would exist before you tried to do your inline binding (which typically should be avoided). As you can see the console is showing the top is changed.

Inline bindings typically need the functions to already be defined before the markup tries to bind them.  If they don't this can result in errors which can halt your scripts.

Its preferred to do your binding inside your logic so that you separate your markup and your logic which provides better decoupling and can centralize your logic and in some cases reduce redundancy.

*Edit: the console logs were just so i could see the change.  They should not have any affect on the script functionality and can be removed.

Comment: So how would I write this script in my actual head tag? Do I need to do anything more to identify that I'm using jquery?

Comment: That would be just placing it in your <head></head> inside a <script></script> pair.  Just make sure it appears after your other script includes.

Comment: the only thing is I already put that into my script tags in the head of the html document but no luck

Comment: Can you update your question with your current situation?  Providing what your head looks like could be useful too possibly.

Comment: I have posted the information you have asked :)

Comment: I don't see your jquery include before the script I also don't see the closing </head> tag

Comment: It's put into my java script tags, right before the body onload

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99628/discussion-between-taplar-and-mathew-crogan).

Answer (score -1):

try this instead:

`$(function() {
  $( '#image' ).css({
    'top': "" + ($("#maincontent").outerHeight(true)/2)-255 + "px"
  });
});`

but in your jsfiddle, it looks like you want this instead:

`$(function() {
  $( '#Header' ).css({
    'top': "" + ($("#maincontent").outerHeight(true)/2)-255 + "px"
  });
});`

but the bigger thing, to me, is that you have 2 id's having header.  the outter div "and" the inner image.

change the id's to be unique.  header-main.  header-image.  change the code as needed.

Comment: you sure?  then i'd question wether or not image is and `id` or `class` - or if you're getting a value for #mainContent, etc.

Comment: still didn't work. You can mess around with the jsfiddle if you want

Comment: all the code I used is in the link in the OP

Comment: yeah i updated my comment.   you have both an invalid selector, and also naming convention issues.  ids should be unique for instance.

Comment: Where do I have a header id in my image?

Comment: in the very first div container after your body tag: <div id="header">
<a href="../Module 10/Index.html" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('Header','','../Module 10/website_design_dpk-roll.png',1)"><img src="../Module 10/website_design_dpk.png" alt="Header that leads back to index page" width="850" height="320" id="Header" /></a> </div>

Comment: Yes that's the only place however that doesn't make much difference. That's not the image I'm talking about. I'm talking about the image div located after the maincontent tag

Comment: roger thanks for the heads up